# Javascript - put Destructed items into a new variable

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use Destructing on a variable. Using the example from MDN:

```
 var people = [
     {
         name: 'Mike Smith',
         family: {
             mother: 'Jane Smith',
             father: 'Harry Smith',
             sister: 'Samantha Smith'
        },
        age: 35
     },
     {
        name: 'Tom Jones',
        family: {
            mother: 'Norah Jones',
            father: 'Richard Jones',
            brother: 'Howard Jones'
     },
       age: 25
    }
];

for (var {name: n, family: {father: f}} of people) {
  console.log('Name: ' + n + ', Father: ' + f);
  //Put results into a variable here
}

// "Name: Mike Smith, Father: Harry Smith"
// "Name: Tom Jones, Father: Richard Jones"
```

The above will split out 2 lines in a loop. What I would like is for the information that results from the for-in loop to be put back into a new variable, so that I can send it from the server (using Express.js) to the client.

Comment: ... so do that. Did you have a question? Please review [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try again.

Comment: you have nothing to do with destructing a var here. The Question's title is mis leading. Just put the newly structured data in an array and send back to server using AJAX or sth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you just need to push it into an array (or whatever):

```
var people = [
     {
         name: 'Mike Smith',
         family: {
             mother: 'Jane Smith',
             father: 'Harry Smith',
             sister: 'Samantha Smith'
        },
        age: 35
     },
     {
        name: 'Tom Jones',
        family: {
            mother: 'Norah Jones',
            father: 'Richard Jones',
            brother: 'Howard Jones'
     },
       age: 25
    }
];

var results = []

for (var {name: name, family: {father: father}} of people) {
  results.push({ name, father })
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
// => [{"name":"Mike Smith","father":"Harry Smith"},{"name":"Tom Jones","father":"Richard Jones"}]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bcLour92/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
let results = [];
for (var {name: n, family: {father: f}} of people) {
  const result = 'Name: ' + n + ', Father: ' + f;
  console.log(result);
  results.push(result);
  //Put results into a variable here
}
console.log('results', results);
```

At this point, you can now do whatever you want with this array of results.